# ComboBox String[] & PictureBox

Tags: c#, combobox

Im a novice programmer on C# language,I'am trying to read a file from my Dynamic library

```
 string[] columns;



ComboBoxItemCollection coll = comboBoxEdit2.Properties.Items;
            coll.BeginUpdate();
            try
            {
                Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(Application.StartupPath + "/MyLists.dll");
                System.Resources.ResourceManager resourcemanager = new System.Resources.ResourceManager("ClassLibrary1.Properties.Resources", assembly);

                string[] strArrays15 = resourcemanager.GetString("JobList").Split('\n');

                for (int row = 0; row < strArrays15.Length; row++)
                {
                    columns = strArrays15[row].Split('\t');
                    //  comboBoxEdit2.Items.Add(columns[1]);
                    coll.Add(columns[1]);

                }
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
```

ComboBox will show only Empoyee cell
**I want to make it when I change Employe the picture change**

```
 pictureEdit3.Image = new Bitmap(Application.StartupPath + "/jpg/" + columns[2].ToString() + ".jpg");
```

not working .. only show one picture for all of them .. not sure why

Structure of the file is the Like the following  (just an example):

```
500 Employee1 picture1
501 Employee2 picture2
502 Employee3 picture3
503 Employee4 picture4
504 Employee5 picture5
```

Comment: Where do you set the image? it looks like `columns[2]` will be only relevant to the last row

Comment: Images are on a folder . I read them from application.startup +"/jpg/" folder . as you can see on the code
and 3rd cell = the images names

Comment: Have you sripted the `SelectedIndexChanged` event?

Comment: I don't doubt that, but you set the `columns` in a loop and you don't appear to set the image at the same time before redefining `columns`

Comment: what should I do then ? 
@Taw yes , I used my code of PictureBox there

Comment: There isny enough information here to help any more.. Its not clear where the combobox is involved or where the pictures get stored in your application (not their location on disk)